# Avoiding exit-nodes with ISP-/country-based blocks of a site?

Tags: exit-relays, censorship, blocked

Is it possible to avoid exit-nodes where a site is blocked by the exit-node's ISP (or - I guess - government)?

So my questions are:

- Can specific exit-nodes be "turned off"?
- Can groups of exit nodes be "turned off" based on top-domain and/or on location (ie. country)?
- Is it possible to do the above *only* for specific sites (maybe specified by using regular expressions); Ie. "turn it off" only when visiting sites known to be blocked, but leave them "on" for other (not blocked) sites?

If it's possible, how would I proceed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> Can specific exit-nodes be "turned off"?
>
> Can groups of exit nodes be "turned off" based on top-domain and/or on location (ie. country)?

You can add an `ExcludeNodes` to your `torrc` config file.

From the manpage:

> ExcludeNodes node,node,... A list of identity fingerprints, country
>   codes, and address patterns of nodes to avoid when building a circuit.
>   Country codes are 2-letter ISO3166 codes, and must be wrapped in
>   braces; fingerprints may be preceded by a dollar sign. (Example:
>   ExcludeNodes ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234, {cc},
>   255.254.0.0/8)
>
> By default, this option is treated as a preference that Tor is allowed
>   to override in order to keep working. For example, if you try to
>   connect to a hidden service, but you have excluded all of the hidden
>   service’s introduction points, Tor will connect to one of them anyway.
>   If you do not want this behavior, set the StrictNodes option
>   (documented below).
>
> Note also that if you are a relay, this (and the other node selection
>   options below) only affects your own circuits that Tor builds for you.
>   Clients can still build circuits through you to any node. Controllers
>   can tell Tor to build circuits through any node.
>
> Country codes are case-insensitive. The code "{??}" refers to nodes
>   whose country can’t be identified. No country code, including {??},
>   works if no GeoIPFile can be loaded. See also the GeoIPExcludeUnknown
>   option below.

---

> Is it possible to do the above only for specific sites (maybe specified by using regular expressions); Ie. "turn it off" only when visiting sites known to be blocked, but leave them "on" for other (not blocked) sites?

As far as I know you can't do this easily.